# Bypass/ignore @media query max-width

Tags: css, responsive

I have a responsive CSS file using several `@media query max-width`. Now I want to override or ignore these @media queries to force user to use the desktop version without changing much in CSS. Is there any way that I can do it without touching the original the CSS file or as least as possible.

I can do this using a `resp` class (eg. `<body class="resp">`) as explained [here](https://css-tricks.com/user-opt-out-responsive-design/), but it would require a lot of changes in the original CSS file and it seems impossible when porting the code to React.

```
.page-wrap { width: 80%; }

@media (max-width: 600px) {
   .resp .page-wrap { width: 100%; }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: How many files are there?

Comment: I have only 1 file but about 50 `@media queries`, also I need to port each of them to a React component where I found no way to add a `.resp` class to it like above code, you know for what React is

Comment: I don't know about React but if you just want to ignore/strip out the media query css. It's will be much easier to just make a new file and copy whatever is not in media query to the new file. Original file remains untouched and you have a clean stylesheet with only desktop styles

Comment: Thanks buddy. That should work, I am actually working for a simple method how to control the responsiveness from outside the CSS file with minimal touch of the original CSS or making a new file

Comment: You could control it with a js class on the body and have the responsive css under that class but that's will generate extra css since that class will be on every line of the responsive css. With this class tho, you don't even need media query because you would only have that class when js adds it.